# I got .fileupload is not a function error in my laravel 8 app

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-file-upload

In my Laravel 8 /  jQuery 3.5.1 / bootstrap  4.5.3 app I want to add jQuery-File-Upload library
and adding all files to my project I got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function
```

At line with fileupload calling:

```
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <input id="fileupload"  type="file" class="ad_image_fileupload" name="files[]" >
      </div>


@section('scripts')
    
    <link href="{{ asset('css/gijgo.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/jquery.fileupload.css') }} "/>


    <script src="{{ asset('node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/autonumeric@4.6.0.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
    
    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/fileupload/jquery.fileupload-video.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/gijgo.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
        console.log('resources/views/admin/ads/edit.blade.php::')
        jQuery.noConflict();  //Not to conflict with other scripts
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            console.log('-2 resources/views/admin/ads/edit.blade.php::')


            $('.ad_image_fileupload').fileupload({
               url: href,
               type: "POST",
```

in my resources/views/admin/layouts/app.blade.php :

```
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/plugins.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/solar/bootstrap.min.css') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-confirm.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}" defer></script>
    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/admin/common.js') }}{{  "?dt=".time()  }}"></script>

</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column">
    
    <header>
        @include('admin.layouts.navbar')
    </header>
    <main class="container-fluid flex-fill">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
    
    <footer>
        @include($current_admin_template.'.layouts.footer')
    </footer>
    @yield('scripts')

</div>
</body>
```

and in resources/js/bootstrap.js :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

console.log('resources/js/bootstrap.js::')

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.confirm =  require('jquery-confirm')

    window.toastr =  require('toastr')

    require('bootstrap');
    require('toastr');
    require('bootstrap-notify'); //     <script src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js') }}"></script>

} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');
```

I am sure that fileupload is triggered afetr quesry is loaded.
I tried to change order of files in my blade file, but got this error anyway...

How it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: add this `@yield('scripts')` before body tag not inside `<div></div>`

Comment: No it did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: basically this error usually get wrong order of include js files so you can check with change order

Comment: I tried several variants, as I made in my prior Laravel 5 app, where it worked ok. But failed any order.

Comment: Still suffer this error ... Not any ideas or how to debug it ?

Comment: That is how console of my browser looks like : https://prnt.sc/wes6dq
Apart I use and init gijgo datepicker, tinymce, autonumeric component when jquery is 
inited and they all works ok. I mean jquery was inited ok. Any hints ?